# Can I open and pay into both cash Lifetime ISA and Stocks and Shares LISA in the same year?

Tags: united-kingdom, isa

I have a stocks and shares LISA but as I might want to use the funds in not too distant future I would like to lower the risk of losing a significant portion of the money by also putting some money into regular cash LISA. Can I open and pay into both of these in the same tax year?

```
You can hold cash or stocks and shares in your Lifetime ISA, or have a combination of both.
```

The government website only says hold a combination of both and not pay into and other sites usually said you are only allowed to pay into one LISA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can only have [one of each type of ISA per year](https://www.gov.uk/individual-savings-accounts/how-isas-work).

> Every tax year you can put money into one of each kind of ISA. The tax year runs from 6 April to 5 April.

The [4 types of ISA being](https://www.gov.uk/individual-savings-accounts/how-isas-work)

> There are 4 types of Individual Savings Accounts (ISA):
>
> - cash ISA
> - stocks and shares ISA
> - innovative finance ISA
> - Lifetime ISA

But you could invest more of your allowance in [another type of ISA](https://www.gov.uk/individual-savings-accounts) e.g. a standard cash ISA.

> You can put money into one of each kind of ISA each tax year.

As long as you stay within your total [ISA allowance](https://www.gov.uk/individual-savings-accounts/how-isas-work), so if you buy a LISA the total amount you can save in other types of ISA would be reduced.

> You can save up to £20,000 in one type of account or split the allowance across some or all of the other types.

Answer (score 0):

Simply sell a portion (or all) of your S&S LISA holdings. The cash generated from the sale will still be held in your S&S LISA, albeit with no interest.

Or, if you want to keep your holdings, just top-up your S&S LISA with cash as usual and simply don't invest it.